# How to merge arrays that are passed into the function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, object

So I've been working on my project that involves scraper.

So workflow is next: There are two scrapers right now. Data is being parsed and pushed into array for each individual scraper and passed to the merge component.

So the merge component looks like this:

```
let mergedApartments = []; //Creating merged list of apartments
exports.mergeData = (apartments) => {
  //Fetching all apartments that are passed from scraper(s)
  mergedApartments.push(...apartments); //Pushing apartments into the list
  console.log(mergedApartments.length);
};
```

So right now output of `mergedApartments.length` is `9 39`. So the first function that calls `mergeData()` and pass it an array have 9 objects inside it, and the other scraper have 30 objects inside it's array, who is again passed to the `mergeData`.

Now this is not what I've expected. I've expected one array with all merged objects from the scrapers. Right now, scraperno1 send apartments and it's added to the `mergedApartments`, then scraperno2 sends apartments and it's overwriting that array by adding new apartments objects into the array.

Now I want different output: I just want to get one list with all merged objects from the arrays. Because this data will be passed to the storing component, and I don't want to query DB multiple times, because for each new `mergedApartments` list, data will be inserted and creating duplicate values - throwing an error.

So what I've tried: I've tried creating some kind of a counter which counts number of time that function `mergeData` is called, and then do the logic about merging but no success.

So I just want my array to have one output of `mergedApartments.length` - in this case 39.

Thanks!

**EDIT**
Here how one of the scraper looks:

```
const merge = require('../data-functions/mergeData');
const axios = require('axios');
const cheerio = require('cheerio');

//function for olx.ba scraper. Fetching raw html data and pushing it into array of objects. Passing data to merge function

exports.santScraper = (count) => {
  const url = `https://www.sant.ba/pretraga/prodaja-1/tip-2/cijena_min-20000/stranica-${count}`;

  const santScrapedData = [];
  const getRawData = async () => {
    try {
      await axios.get(url).then((response) => {
        const $ = cheerio.load(response.data);

        $('div[class="col-xxs-12 col-xss-6 col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-lg-4"]').each(
          (index, element) => {
            const getLink = $(element).find('a[class="re-image"]').attr('href');
            const getDescription = $(element).find('a[class="title"]').text();
            const getPrice = $(element)
              .find('div[class="prices"] > h3[class="price"]')
              .text()
              .replace(/\.| ?KM$/g, '')
              .replace(',', '.');
            const getPicture = $(element).find('img').attr('data-original');
            const getSquaremeters = $(element)
              .find('span[class="infoCount"]')
              .first()
              .text()
              .replace(',', '.')
              .split('m')[0];
            const pricepersquaremeter =
              parseFloat(getPrice) / parseFloat(getSquaremeters);

            santScrapedData[index] = {
              id: getLink.substring(42, 46),
              link: getLink,
              descr: getDescription,
              price: Math.round(getPrice),
              pictures: getPicture,
              sqm: Math.round(getSquaremeters),
              ppm2: Math.round(pricepersquaremeter),
            };
          }
        );
        merge.mergeData(santScrapedData); //here i'm calling function and passing array to function
      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };
  getRawData();
};
```

Other scraper looks the same(it's same calling of the function)

Answer (score 2):

For this, you need to use `concat` function from the Array prototype

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat

```
exports.mergeData = (apartments) => {
  mergedApartment = mergedApartments.concat(apartments);
};

exports.sendData = () => {
  console.log(mergedApartment.length);
}
```

and in your main script

```
getRawData().then(merge.sendData);
```

Comment: If I use your solution, output is 9,30 which are number for each apartment list(like I'm getting length of apartments).
I've tried also with 
`mergedApartments = mergedApartments.concat(apartments);

  console.log(mergedApartments.length);`

And this is the same output - problem that I have - it's getting back 9 39. Again it's overwriting itself.

Comment: In this case, you need to add calls of this function to your question, otherwise, it's not enough clear.

Comment: Do you know how many calls would be of `mergeData`? If not you need to split your `mergeData` function into two parts. The first part would just concat two arrays and the second part would save the array to DB or in your case `console.log` its length.
The second part must be called after `getRawData` Promise would be resolved.

Comment: Yeah, it will be called how many scrapers there are. Right now is two scraper functions - two calls of merge data. Each scrapers gets their data and pass it to the `mergeData`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228840/discussion-between-aldinho-and-mike-malyi).